# What are the alternatives to run Spark application in cluster mode?

Tags: apache-spark

I am writing a Spark application by using Scala. My application is packaged in a jar file by using maven, I can run my application in the local mode (standalone) with this command :

```
 spark-submit --class classes.mainClass     --master local --driver-memory 30G logs-0.0.7-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies
```

My question : How I can try my application in cluster mode?
I need to check my application by using 1, 2, 3 ... cluster machines.

Comment: for cluster mode, you just have to specify `--deploy-mode cluster` in `spark-submit` command

Comment: I am using Spark only on local mode, my hope was to find how I can pass to cluster mode, I am student and I have not a cluster of machines, etc. I found Amazon EMR, I tested it and it work.